# Why does returning an object changes the content of that object in C++?

Tags: c++, object, methods, return

I'm new to both C++ and Stackoverflow so be gentle but tell me if something is wrong with my code or my post.

Here is my problem : I am trying to build a matrix class which contains a 1D array (the values) and two int (the dimensions). The problem arises in the method that multiplies the matrices and more precisely when I try to *return* the result:

The resulting matrix has the right coefficients *inside* the multiplication method but the coefficients magically become trash *outside* the method, in the main.

Here is my class :

```
class Matrice {

public:
    // attributes :
    double* values;
    unsigned dim1;
    unsigned dim2;

    // Methods :
    Matrice(double[], int, int);
    double getVal(int, int);
    void setVal(int, int, double);
    void printValues();
    double computeCoeff(int , int, Matrice);
    Matrice mult(Matrice B);
};
```

now here is the code from the multiplication method :

```
Matrice Matrice::mult(Matrice B){
    int tabSize = dim1*(B.dim2);
    double matTab[tabSize];

    for(int i=0; i<dim1;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<B.dim2;j++){
                        
            matTab[i*B.dim2+j]=computeCoeff(i, j, B);
        }
    }
    Matrice C = Matrice(matTab, dim1, B.dim2);
    std::cout<<"before the return :"<<std::endl;
    C.printValues();
    return C;
}
```

And now we get to the interesting part. When I create two instances of Matrice and multiply them with the following code :

```
int main(){

    double matA[12] = {1, 2, 3,
                    4, 5, 6, 
                    7, 8, 9,
                    10, 11, 12};
    Matrice A = Matrice(matA, 4, 3);

    double matB[6] = {1, 1,
                    1, 1,
                    1, 1};

    Matrice B = Matrice(matB, 3, 2);

    Matrice C = A.mult(B);

    std::cout<<"after the return :"<<std::endl;
    C.printValues();

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following text in my console :

```
before the return :
dim1 = 4
dim2 = 2
6 6
15 15
24 24
33 33
after the return :
dim1 = 4
dim2 = 2
1.81868e+231 1.73843e-310
1.96491e+231 1.81504e-307
1.30394e+231 1.81488e-307
1.85708e+231 1.82192e-307
```

As you probably have guessed the first matrix is the one with the good coefficients and the coefficients in the second one are garbage. It looks like when returning it copied the two integers ok but created a new array without assigning its values to anything and I really have no idea why. Since the matrix just before the return is correct I assumed that none of the other methods can be the culprit.

When I looked how to return objects on forums people said that one could use fancy pointer stuff to avoid copying the object but that, in general, it is ok to return an object. Apparently in most cases the compiler even gets that it doesn't have to actually copy the object and then, returning an object, really is ok (or is it?).

I really want to understand how it works so any help is welcome.

EDIT :

other methods :

The constructor :

```
Matrice::Matrice(double givenValues[], int givenDim1, int givenDim2){
    values = givenValues;
    dim1 = givenDim1;
    dim2 = givenDim2;
}
```

The getVal, setVal, computeCoeff and printValues methods :

```
double Matrice::getVal(int i, int j){
    return values[i*dim2+j];
}

void Matrice::setVal(int i, int j, double val){
    values[i*dim2+j] = val;
}

double Matrice::computeCoeff(int i, int j, Matrice B){

    double coef=0;
    for(int k=0; k<dim2;k++){
        coef+=getVal(i, k)*B.getVal(k, j);
    }

    return coef;
}

void Matrice::printValues(){

    std::cout << "dim1 = "<<dim1<<std::endl;
    std::cout << "dim2 = "<<dim2<<std::endl;

    for(int i=0; i<dim1;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<dim2;j++){
            std::cout<<getVal(i, j)<< " ";

        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Although there is nothing wrong with something in the object changing as a result of it returning, in C++ (as a result of an implicit copy) the usual reason for that [is demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). I see at least two common programming mistakes that could possibly occur here. At least one programming mistake is guaranteed here, possibly two,  but unfortunately because the shown code fails to meet all requirements of a [mre], it is not possible to authoritatively confirm that. See [ask] questions for more information.

Comment: In particular, please show the definition of `Matrice` constructor.

Comment: It looks like you don't handle `double* values` field properly. You probably do plain assign and then all hell breaks loose. The only sensible way is to allocate memory and create a copy in `Matrice(double[], int, int);` constructor. With that you have to free memory as well but you don't have the destructor declared. This suggests that the content of `Matrice(double[], int, int);` constructor is wrong. Show us the constructor to confirm that.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I just edited the post and added the code from the constructor and the other methods.

Comment: @freakish I'm not sure to understand what you mean (and it's probably why my code is failing)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen @ Sam Varshavchik I updated the post and I put the rest of the code. If you include iostream and copy/paste all the pieces you should be able to compile and reproduce the error.

Comment: @NokiYola There's a long journey ahead of you, my friend. This line `values = givenValues;` is wrong. You only assign **the address** of `givenValues` to `values`. But the content changes because `givenAddress` is defined on the stack (and the compiler is allowed to mutate those values). You need to allocate memory `values = new double[givenDim1 * givenDim2];` and do a copy instead. You also need the destructor to free that memory. And copy constructors/assignements to avoid unwanted sharing. As you can see, there's a lot about C++ you still need to learn.

Comment: @freakish Thank you for your answer! I hope one day I'll be done with noob questions ^^. If I were to sum up what you said I should copy objects when assigning them. Is that correct? If it is I am quite astonished to find this kind of things happening on a type as native as an array of doubles. Also I thought there was a specific syntaxe for this, like `int a; int& b=a;`

Comment: @freakish ok I think I finally got what you meant and you were right, I have a long journey ahead! I'm doing the same error twice : in `values = givenValues;` I'm not copying arrays but pointers and in `Matrice C = A.mult(B);` the default copy constructor does the same error for me. Finally I should implement a destructor because the default destructor currently deletes the pointer `double* values;` in my class but not what it's pointing at. When I'm done I'll post my edited code as an answer. Thanks everyone for your help!